# how to block referrerpolicy="no-referrer" in iframe

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

I am running youtube to mp3 converter and people using our iframe API for accessing our API service
now problem is some people using iframe with `referrerpolicy="no-referrer"` tags, so I cant block them
if I want to block any specific website that not access our API, I m using the following code its working fine `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(http(s)?://([^\.]+\.)?domain\.com) [NC]` but when anybody use `referrerpolicy="no-referrer"` in iframe I cant block them so I want to know how I can block such a website which using such a tag in there iframe and bypass sandbox

Answer (score 0):

It’s really simple though? In your service, look at the `Referer` header. Is it present? All good. Is it missing? Deny access.

The “deny access” part could of course be made to be somewhat user-friendly.

Comment: where i can check such referer settings or how I need to block via htaccess or any otherway that no body access our iframe that use referrerpolicy="no-referrer"

Comment: You can use a `RewriteCond` like you did, just check if the header matches `^$` (empty string).

Comment: i use them but no luck when other users do not use no-referrer policy i can easily block them but when people use no-referrer policy in their iframe i cant block them so I want a good solution how to block them.